# matplotlib plot x-axis is not scaling to x-axis array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm programming in python Jupiter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
x #array float64. values range from 0 to 5
y #array float64. values range from 1*10**-14 to 1*10**-16
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yscale('log)
```

[image: graph]

I get this where the x-scale is completely off given my axis goes from ~0 to ~5.2. Using plt.xlim(0,5) does not help either.
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  Can you show your x and y data?

Comment: Rather your `y` values seem fall in the range `0-5.2`

Comment: The last line of your code will throw an error. Please post the full code that generated the figure, including the data.

Comment: Are you sure the x-values are all float and not strings?